# Are correlators constructed out of Wilson loops singular in pure Yang-Mills?

Tags: gauge-theory, yang-mills, correlation-functions, wilson-loop

If I have some gauge invariant function of two Wilson loops (such as $\left<\text{Tr}W_1 \text{Tr}W_2\right>$) does the expectation value diverge when the loops coincide the same way $\left<\phi(x)\phi(y)\right>$ diverges when $x=y$ for a scalar theory? Does it diverge if they only partially coincide along some segment? Does it diverge if they intersect at only a point? Is it even possible for these correlation functions to diverge since the traces are bounded?